# apache can't start in wamp server

Tags: apache, wamp, wampserver

localhost not work and IIS server stop
apache error log look like this

```
[Thu Jan 05 14:55:20 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.21 (Win32) PHP/5.3.8 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Jan 05 14:55:20 2012] [notice] Server built: Sep 10 2011 11:34:11
[Thu Jan 05 14:55:20 2012] [notice] Parent: Created child process 3152
[Thu Jan 05 14:55:20 2012] [notice] Child 3152: Child process is running
[Thu Jan 05 14:55:20 2012] [crit] (OS 10022)An invalid argument was supplied.  : Child 3152: setup_inherited_listeners(), WSASocket failed to open the inherited socket.
[Thu Jan 05 14:55:21 2012] [crit] Parent: child process exited with status 3 -- Aborting.
[Thu Jan 05 14:55:31 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.21 (Win32) PHP/5.3.8 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Jan 05 14:55:31 2012] [notice] Server built: Sep 10 2011 11:34:11
[Thu Jan 05 14:55:31 2012] [notice] Parent: Created child process 3988
[Thu Jan 05 14:55:31 2012] [notice] Child 3988: Child process is running
[Thu Jan 05 14:55:31 2012] [crit] (OS 10022)An invalid argument was supplied.  : Child 3988: setup_inherited_listeners(), WSASocket failed to open the inherited socket.
[Thu Jan 05 14:55:31 2012] [crit] Parent: child process exited with status 3 -- Aborting.
```

anyone know reason for this plz help for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be a common issue on Win XP SP2.

"
The very simple solution is to uncheck the “Enable LMHOSTS Lookup” box in the TCP/IP protocol setup (under WINS setting). Here are the steps to do this:

Open “Control Panel” then “Network Connections.”
Right-click on “Local Area Connection” and select “Properties.”
Double-click on the “Internet Protocol (TCP/IP)” line to open the “Properties.”
On the “General” tab, click the “Advanced” button.
Select the “WINS” tab and uncheck the “Enable LMHOSTS Lookup” box.”
"

http://www.jennyconnors.com/computers/installing-apache2-and-the-wsasocket-failed-to-open-the-inherited-socket-error

Answer (score 5):

If you guys have still have problems with this after trying everything (like me) and the wampserver icon remains orange or some internal exception is thrown while trying to put it online, try to do following steps:

1. Left click the wampserver icon
2. Navigate to Apache->Service
3. Press "Remove service" and then navigate there again and press "Install service"
4. Restart wampserver, start/restart all services and try to put it online again
5. you can check out if the port 80 is open for wampserver by clicking "test port 80" inside the Apache->Service  submenu

There is apparently some kind of bug or misunderstanding and wampserver didn't knew where the apache is installed

Comment: If you're running Skype, know that it likes to take port 80. The easiest fix for this conflict is to start Wamp before Skype.

Comment: Awesome.. This worked for me. Thanks a lot. I was scratching my head since hours :-)

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem. It usually means that either your

- C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
- C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\lmhosts.sam

file has been changed by a program or virus.

Under Win XP SP2 or SP3, "hosts" should contain 1 entry:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
```

lmhosts.sam should have a load of commented out statements using `#`.

Viruses and malware will try to put their own entries in there, so check every IP address or hostname listed. `127.0.0.1` is the local host machine, so thats cool.

Answer (score 0):

i think that the problem is Related to httpd.conf file open it & change Port 80 to ex: 8081 because it could be used by another programs then try to Restart services and type http:\localhost:8081 you will find it runs