# WampServer Apache not starting

Tags: php, apache, wamp, wampserver

I've installed `WampServer` so many times, and everytime i face this problem.

The `wamp` tray icon is orange :

[image: wamp tray icon is orange]

and i get this errors in the `Apache Error Log` :

> [Sun May 31 07:29:32.246382 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2972:tid 376] AH00455: Apache/2.4.9 (Win32) PHP/5.5.12 configured -- resuming normal operations
>
> [Sun May 31 07:29:32.246382 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2972:tid 376] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Mar 16 2014 12:13:13
>
> [Sun May 31 07:29:32.246382 2015] [core:notice] [pid 2972:tid 376] AH00094: Command line: 'f:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\bin\httpd.exe -d F:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9'
>
> [Sun May 31 07:29:32.527182 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2972:tid 376] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 2700
>
> [Sun May 31 07:29:59.421630 2015] [mpm_winnt:crit] [pid 2972:tid 376] AH00419: master_main: create child process failed. Exiting.

When i test the `port 80` it says :

[image]

Checked the System `Environment Variables` for errors and understood nothing there :

[image]

**What Causes this problem?**

Comment: Have you had a look on [that one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8741526/apache-cant-start-in-wamp-server)?

Comment: @D4V1D yes, still facing those errors in the log file.

Comment: Did you download [that](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679)?

Comment: @D4V1D yes, i have from version 2005 to v 2013 installed.

Comment: Is the Apache service installed? Click WAMP icon, and under Apache go to service. If it isn't started, click "Install Service". Then restart wamp.

Comment: Forgot to also mention, Skype messes with Apache. You have to go into Skype's settings and tell it to use an alternate port.

Comment: Tried this solution 10 times and doesn't work, also i don't have skype installed.
when i remove apache service and re-install it, some error alerts poping up, and when no alerts it doesn't work also. i'm going too crazy to fix this problem.

Comment: `some error alerts poping up` - What error? Your problem isn't wamp, it's apache.

Comment: Have a look about what i'm talking about : http://i.stack.imgur.com/oU82O.png

Comment: Open command prompt, navigate to where apache is installed (ex: `C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\bin`). Then type: `httpd.exe -k install`. Does it give you a useful error?

Comment: @WadeShuler no it says successfully installed apache. but still the same problem.

Comment: @AmrSubZero Ok, same thing from the command line, now try to start it: `httpd.exe -k start`, does it give you any error?

Comment: Yes, it gives me an error. maybe it says something like apache not found or not installed and can't find it. as much i can remember.

Comment: @AmrSubZero as much as you can remember? You don't have to remember anything... Copy and paste the error here..

Answer (score 0):

Please check that you have the [Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012 Update 4](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=30679) installed on this computer.

Apache 2.4.9 requires this library to be installed.

Click the download button and then select either the X86(32bit) or X64(64bit) link to match the version of WAMPServer(32 or 64) that you installed.

If you are running on a 64bit Windows, its a good idea to download and install both the 64 and 32 bit libraries, as something somewhere you use in the future will also require the library.

Comment: i assume that you didn't read the comments,
visual c++ installed from v2005 to v2013 latest updates.
and still facing the same problems.

Comment: Did you install the runtimes before or after you installed WAMPServer?

Comment: Before installing wamp.